# PHP/MySQL: Inserting commas to separate variables pulled from html form in to MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, select

i'm currently working on a script to randomize different values of input. Here is the main part of the php script:

```
$alive='';
if(isset($_GET['alive'])) {
$alive=$_GET['alive'];
}
$injured='';
if(isset($_GET['injured'])) {
$injured=$_GET['injured'];
}
$deceased='';
if(isset($_GET['deceased'])) {
$deceased=$_GET['deceased'];
}
$unkstat='';
if(isset($_GET['unkstat'])) {
$unkstat=$_GET['unkstat'];
}
$found='';
if(isset($_GET['found'])) {
$found=$_GET['found'];
}
$missing='';
if(isset($_GET['missing'])) {
$missing=$_GET['missing'];
}
$youth='';
if(isset($_GET['youth'])) {
$youth=$_GET['youth'];
}
$adult='';
if(isset($_GET['adult'])) {
$adult=$_GET['adult'];
}
$unkage='';
if(isset($_GET['unkage'])) {
$unkage=$_GET['unkage'];
}
$incidentid='';
if(isset($_GET['incidentid'])) {
$incidentid=$_GET['incidentid'];
}
$limit='';
if(isset($_GET['limit'])) {
$limit=$_GET['limit'];
}

mysql_connect ("$host", "$username", "$password") or die ("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (given_name, family_name, gender, status, age, incidentid)
select First10.$gender, Last10.family_name,
(SELECT $gender from gender) AS Gender,
(SELECT * FROM status WHERE status IN ($alive $injured $deceased $unkstat $found $missing)) AS Status,
(SELECT * FROM age WHERE age IN ($youth $adult $unkage)) AS Age,
(SELECT $incidentid from incidentid) AS Incident_ID
from ( select fn.$gender, @fns := @fns + 1 as Sequence
from ( select $gender from fnames where $gender IS NOT NULL order by rand() limit 100) fn,
(select @fns := 0 ) vars ) First10
JOIN
( select ln.family_name, @lns := @lns + 1 as Sequence
from ( select family_name from lastnames order by rand() limit 100 ) ln,
(select @lns := 0 ) vars ) Last10
ON First10.Sequence = Last10.Sequence";
```

And the html is here:

```
<p>
Status: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="alive" value="'alive'">Alive and Well<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="injured" value="'injured'">Injured<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="deceased" value="'deceased'">Deceased<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="unkstat" value="'unknown'">Unknown<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="found" value="'found'">Found<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="missing" value="'missing'">Missing<BR>
</p>

<p>
Age: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="youth" value="'youth'">Youth (0-17)<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="adult" value="'adult'">Adult (18+)<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="unkage" value="'unknown'">Unknown<BR>
</p
```

What I am trying to do is pull the values from the checkboxes and insert the checked values into a mysql query. The query will then search for these values in premade tables and insert them into a separate table. My problem here is that whenever I pull in the variables, I receive a syntax error that usually results in something like this:

> 'SELECT * FROM status WHERE status IN ('alive' 'injured' 'deceased' )
>   AS Status'

It appears that the values within the parenthesis require commas to separate them, but I cannot think of, nor find a way to efficiently do this. Please advise. You guys are great :)

Comment: Totally off topic: instead of doing all those variable set. I would have created an array with all the varnames and loop through them.  
`$vars = array('alive', 'injured', 'deceased', 'unkstat', 'found', 'etc', );
$result = array();
foreach($vars as $var) {
    $result[$var] = '';
    if (isset($_GET[$var])) $result[$var] = $_GET[$var];
}`

Comment: That was my original code, and I did have an array, but I had problems with it and experimented with my current method. Your array, however, seems to work much better than what I previously had.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array. Push each set value to the array using `array_push`. Then use `implode(",",$array)` to create comma separated value variable. Use that within your IN statement

Example in conjunction with PeeHaa's response.

```
$vars = array('alive', 'injured', 'deceased', 'unkstat', 'found', 'etc', ); 
$result = array(); 
foreach($vars as $var) { 
   if (isset($_GET[$var])) {
     array_push($_GET[$var], $result);
   }
}
$result = implode(",",$result);
```

Comment: PeeHaa's response is also a more efficient way to check all those values. Do that as well.

Comment: Also, ternary operators will clean up your code a good bit. Try doing this: $myValue = (isset($myValue)) ? $myValue : '';

Comment: This works wonders, and it is much better than my previous attempt to do the arrays...

Comment: Sorry for bothering you guys, but I think I edited the code a tad and now whenever I try to run the query, it seems to search for "Array" instead of the actual info. Can you guys help me out with this please?

Answer (score 3):

**May I suggest a slightly better solution.** You can create forms that return an `array` to PHP by adding square brackets at the end of the name (e.g. `status[]`). Using an array will keep you PHP code short as you don't need to look for each variable separately. For instance:

**HTML:**

```
<p>
Status: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="status[]" value="alive">Alive and Well<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="status[]" value="injured">Injured<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="status[]" value="deceased">Deceased<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="status[]" value="unknown">Unknown<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="status[]" value="found">Found<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="status[]" value="missing">Missing<BR>
</p>
```

**PHP:**

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM status WHERE status IN ("' . implode('","', array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['status'])) . '")';
```

The [`implode`](https://www.php.net/implode) function will join the data together. I've also added an [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map) call that will run every array value through [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to escape the value, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$in_clause = '';
$in_clause_t = '';

$alive='';
if(isset($_GET['alive'])) {
    $alive=$_GET['alive'];
    $in_clause .= $alive . ", ";
}
$injured='';
if(isset($_GET['injured'])) {
    $injured=$_GET['injured'];
    $in_clause .= $injured . ", ";
}
$deceased='';
if(isset($_GET['deceased'])) {
    $deceased=$_GET['deceased'];
    $in_clause .= $deceased . ", ";
}
$unkstat='';
if(isset($_GET['unkstat'])) {
    $unkstat=$_GET['unkstat'];
    $in_clause .= $unkstat . ", ";
}
$found='';
if(isset($_GET['found'])) {
    $found=$_GET['found'];
    $in_clause .= $found . ", ";
}
$missing='';
if(isset($_GET['missing'])) {
    $missing=$_GET['missing'];
    $in_clause .= $missing . ", ";
}
$youth='';
if(isset($_GET['youth'])) {
    $youth=$_GET['youth'];
    $in_clause_t .= $youth . ", ";
}
$adult='';
if(isset($_GET['adult'])) {
    $adult=$_GET['adult'];
    $in_clause_t .= $adult . ", ";
}
$unkage='';
if(isset($_GET['unkage'])) {
    $unkage=$_GET['unkage'];
    $in_clause_t .= $unkage . ", ";
}
$incidentid='';
if(isset($_GET['incidentid'])) {
    $incidentid=$_GET['incidentid'];
}
$limit='';
if(isset($_GET['limit'])) {
    $limit=$_GET['limit'];
}

if (strlen($in_clause) > 0) {
    $in_clause = substr($in_clause, 0, (strlen($in_clause) - 2));
}

if (strlen($in_clause_t) > 0) {
    $in_clause_t = substr($in_clause_t, 0, (strlen($in_clause_t) - 2));
}

mysql_connect ("$host", "$username", "$password") or die ("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (given_name, family_name, gender, status, age, incidentid)
select First10.$gender, Last10.family_name,
(SELECT $gender from gender) AS Gender,
(SELECT * FROM status WHERE status IN (" . $in_clause . ") AS Status,
(SELECT * FROM age WHERE age IN (" . $in_clause_t . ")) AS Age,
(SELECT $incidentid from incidentid) AS Incident_ID
from ( select fn.$gender, @fns := @fns + 1 as Sequence
from ( select $gender from fnames where $gender IS NOT NULL order by rand() limit 100) fn,
(select @fns := 0 ) vars ) First10
JOIN
( select ln.family_name, @lns := @lns + 1 as Sequence
from ( select family_name from lastnames order by rand() limit 100 ) ln,
(select @lns := 0 ) vars ) Last10
ON First10.Sequence = Last10.Sequence";
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

With your current set-up, add commas after each variable to the problem statement:

```
SELECT * FROM status WHERE status IN ($alive, $injured, $deceased, $unkstat, $found, $missing)) AS Status
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a botch but this could work....

Basically form a comma seperated list of all $_POST variables...

```
<form action="" method="post">

<p>
Status: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="alive" value="'alive'">Alive and Well<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="injured" value="'injured'">Injured<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="deceased" value="'deceased'">Deceased<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="unkstat" value="'unknown'">Unknown<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="found" value="'found'">Found<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="missing" value="'missing'">Missing<BR>
</p>

<p>
Age: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="youth" value="'youth'">Youth (0-17)<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="adult" value="'adult'">Adult (18+)<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX name="unkage" value="'unknown'">Unknown<BR>
</p>

<input type="submit">


<?php 

if(isset($_POST)) {
    print_r($_POST);
    $str = implode(",",$_POST);
    echo $str;
}

?>
```